# test if CComPtr is null in COM

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, com

I have a question regarding the usage of COM smart pointer class `CComPtr`. I was following an example from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98.aspx) and it seems the code does not call `CoCreateInstance()` on the `CComPtr` (it merely declares it before assigning it value).

So I wrote a test program like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "atlbase.h"
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CComPtr<int> myint = nullptr;
    if (myint == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "yes" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And it gives the following error in visual-studio 2013:

```
------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------

  ConsoleApplication2.cpp

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(177): error C2227: left of '->Release' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

          type is 'int *'

          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(175) : while compiling class template member function 'ATL::CComPtrBase::~CComPtrBase(void) throw()'

          with

          [

              T=int

          ]

          c:\users\calvi_000\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp(18) : see reference to function template instantiation 'ATL::CComPtrBase::~CComPtrBase(void) throw()' being compiled

          with

          [

              T=int

          ]

          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\atlmfc\include\atlcomcli.h(317) : see reference to class template instantiation 'ATL::CComPtrBase' being compiled

          with

          [

              T=int

          ]

          c:\users\calvi_000\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp(10) : see reference to class template instantiation 'ATL::CComPtr' being compiled

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Why is it illegal to assign a `nullptr` to a `CComPtr` object ?  Is there any method that we can use to check whether or not a `CComPtr` owns any objects ? Will a call like `if (myint == nullptr)` enough to check if this smart pointer does not own any object ?

Comment: CComPtr is a smart pointer wrapper for COM interface pointers.  The kind that derive from IUnknown.  Using *int* doesn't make any sense.  You get the compile error because *int* doesn't have a Release() method.  Automatically called by CComPtr in its destructor, the smart part.

Comment: but how do I check if a CComPtr owns any object ? Just a  "if(ccomPtr)" will do the trick ?

Comment: You already know how to do that, the one thing you did not get wrong.

Answer (score 9):

> Why is it illegal to assign a nullptr to a CComPtr object ?

It is not.  As Hans pointed out, `CComPtr` can only be used with COM interfaces, `int` is not a compatible type.  That is what the compiler error is telling you:

```
error C2227: left of '->Release' must point to class/struct/union/generic type

          type is 'int *'
```

So the problem is not that you are assigning `nullptr`, but that `int` does not have a `Release()` method, which `CComPtr` requires.  An `IUnknown` (or derived) interface does have a `Release()` method.

> Is there any method that we can use to check whether or not a `CComPtr` owns any objects ? Will a call like `if (myint == nullptr)` enough to check if this smart pointer does not own any object ?

If you read the [`CComPtr` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98.aspx) more carefully, you would see that `CComPtr` derives from `CComPtrBase`, which implements `operator!()`, `operator T*()` and `operator==()` operators (so `CComPtr` will *act* like a raw pointer), as well as an `IsEqualObject()` method:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CComPtr<IUnknown> myUnk = nullptr;
    if (!myUnk) { // calls myUnk.operator!() ...
        std::cout << "null" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "not null" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CComPtr<IUnknown> myUnk = nullptr;
    if (myUnk) { // calls myUnk.operator IUnknown*() ...
        std::cout << "not null" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "null" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CComPtr<IUnknown> myUnk = nullptr;
    if (myUnk == nullptr) { // calls myUnk.operator==(IUnknown*) ...
        std::cout << "null" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "not null" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CComPtr<IUnknown> myUnk = nullptr;
    if (myUnk.IsEqualObject(nullptr)) {
        std::cout << "null" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "not null" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```